# rewrite Query in sql

Tags: sql

can anyone write this query without any subqueries (SQL, Database Systems)

```
SELECT
    title
FROM
    Movies AS Old
WHERE
    year < ANY (
        SELECT
            year
        FROM
            Movies
        WHERE
            title = Old.title
  );
```

What is query does is **finds older releases of the same title**

(note: this comes from the relation `Movies(title, year, length, genre, studioName, producer)`)

i have tried but i can't achieve it:

```
SELECT title
FROM Movies Old
Where Old.title = Old.title and Old.year < [year]
```

Comment: why don't you give it a try and seem what you come up with?

Comment: What is this query meant to accomplish? If the `Movies` data has no duplicate `title` values then this query will return no data.

Comment: create your own query and if it encounters sql query error, post the query that you created.

Comment: @jdigital if venkat is wasting his time in asking this question, that means he must have tried himself, he's not able to solve his question that's why he's here, and we should respect and help them best.

Comment: i'm guessing it tries to find older releases of the same title

Comment: yes... @muratgu

Comment: @venkat what you want is to get the previous data with same title of each latest song? like what if they have 3 same title different year which want should you get? like 2014, 15, 16

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use a Sub query you can join the table onto itself:

```
SELECT Old.title, Old.Year, New.Year
FROM Movies AS Old
INNER JOIN Movies AS New ON Old.Title = New.Title
WHERE Old.Year <> New.Year
```

Comment: which DB eingine are you using?

Comment: Try it now please, i forgot to add the Alias prefix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT old.title,old.year
FROM Movies AS OLD
INNER JOIN Movies AS New ON Old.Title = New.Title
WHERE Old.Year < New.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT old.title,old.year FROM Movies AS OLD INNER JOIN Movies AS New ON Old.Title = New.Title WHERE DATEDIFF(Year,Old.Year,New.Year) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT old.title AS title, MIN(old.year) AS olderyear
FROM Movies AS old
INNER JOIN Movies AS new ON old.Title = new.Title 
GROUP BY old.title
```

For example, in MySQL:

```
id  year    title
-----------------
1   2013    a
2   2015    a
6   2016    a
9   2014    a
3   2014    b
4   2016    b
8   2010    b
5   2014    c
```

results:

```
title  olderyear
--------------
a   2013
b   2010
c   2014
```